# How to change a referenced classprovider in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, launch

I uninstalled the maven plugin but when trying to run the project that was perfectly running before the plugin I have "Referenced classpath provider does not exist: org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathprovider". I assume I have to change the launch configuration for the project. Can anyone provide the steps to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 34):

This helped me http://sha.nnoncarey.com/blog/archives/33

> If you get this error when launching a Run Configuration in Eclipse with the IAM (Maven) >plugin:
>
> Referenced classpath provider does not exist: >org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathProvider
>
> It’s probably because your Run Configuration was created on an old project, and has bad >entries in the Classpath section. The solution is to delete the Run Configuration and create >a new one.

Answer (score 4):

The project could be having old/incorrect settings. Assuming it is a maven project, one possibility is you could regenerate the Eclipse settings for the project by

`mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`

Answer (score 2):

This link helped me:
http://osdir.com/ml/web.webobjects.woproject.devel/2005-09/msg00090.html

I commented out string with CLASSPATH_PROVIDER.