# Eclipse: Referenced classpath provider does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my attempt to lighten my eclipse, I uninstalled some plugins.

After that I can't run my projects anymore. I get this error:

> Referenced classpath provider does not exist: 
>   org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider

How can I recover from this?

I don't remember which plugins I removed.

I am using Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: I highly suggest you to re-download a Eclipse, maybe you have messed up some of the plugins

Comment: What type of application is it? Eclipse RCP?

Comment: +1 to you all. I use the latest Eclipse Juno. No need to worry about those configurations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple solution to get your launch configurations running again, is to right click on your project within the IDE and then choose Configure -> Convert to Maven Project. This fixes the broken launch configuration and also brings back the "Maven" context menu entry for the project.

Comment: Convert to Maven Project option is missing.

Comment: I guess Maven is not installed properly in your eclipse IDE

Comment: I might have removed plugins for maven.

Comment: I remember there was a plugin with a name having 'Maven' and 'WTP', I removed it. Is this the one?

Comment: Let me find out maven installation process for you

Comment: Click Help=>Eclipse Market Place=> Search "Maven Integration for eclipse" and click install button.

Comment: Are you able to install Maven

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you are trying a Run Configuration which has dependency to the uninstalled plugin. Delete the Run Configuration for that project and re create it.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094439/how-to-change-a-referenced-classprovider-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the issue on Eclipse

"Referenced classpath provider does not exist: org.eclipse.buildship.core.classpathprovider"

when running an application, I solved the problem by

1. going to the "Eclipse Marketplace"
2. searched by "buildship"
3. updated the "Buildship Gradle Integration" plugin (click button update)
4. restarted Eclipse

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Helped me after I converted my project to JPA project and got the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try to [restore your old configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-123.htm):

1. Click `Help > About` and then click command link `Installation Details...`.
2. Click the `Installation History` tab to see a list of previously saved configurations. Selecting each configuration will show you what was installed in that configuration. When you have found the configuration to which you want to revert, click `Revert`.
3. Click `Yes` when asked to exit and restart the workbench.

Failing this, @PradeepSimha is right: it would be best just to reinstall Eclipse. Otherwise the chances are you will run into same trouble in the future, possibly when you forget the reason for it.

Comment: Awesome - thank you.

I never knew this existed, and was just about to re-install, but I saw this answer and it saved me hours !

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error, without uninstalling any eclipse plugins. Maybe some of the plugins got updated. I was not able to run any project, even a simple Main class with a simple print-out failed.

What helped me is to run `eclipse.exe -clean`.
Open command prompt, then go to eclipse directory and run `eclipse.exe -clean`, then open your workspace and start working as usual.

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the m2e  (maven2eclipse) plugin.

Go to Eclipse market place and download+install.  It should be fixed after that - this worked for me.

If you haven't marketplace available in your eclipse installation, go to "help/Install new Software" and enter the link http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem as you.
Please make sure that your workspace name and project name are different along with the above mentioned configurations.

Answer (score 1):

How to fix this :

1. Click on run configuration
2. Classpath tab
3. Restore default entries

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and I solved by those steps:
Right click on the project > Maven > Update project > OK
then from the menu:
Project > clean

and restart your IDE

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, checked the configuration in properties of that particular project, found Java Compiler -> JDK compliance being disabled and unchecked. Tried some options to get it enabled bt no luck
Had to create a new project and it got resolved.