# Trying to switch from Maven to Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle

My boss recently decided to switch our java project from being built with Maven to being built with Gradle. I updated my local project from our SVN repo, and now I can't get the project to build. I've installed the Gradle plugin for Eclipse, but every time I try to run I get this error:

> Referenced classpath provider does not exist: org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider

It seems like it's still trying to build with Maven. I can't figure out how to fix it and get it to build with Gradle. Is there a file somewhere I need to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely it is trying to launch something using a launch (Run/Debug) configuration that has a Maven classpath element in it. You can delete launch configuration like this and create new ones with your current project.

Also see similar [Eclipse: Referenced classpath provider does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952332/eclipse-referenced-classpath-provider-does-not-exist) and bunch of other question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `build.gradle` and ensure that the project can be build from command line.
After you are satisfied with the results, do change Eclipse configuration file.

That is one of reason [Nodeclipse/Enide Gradle for Eclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle)
([marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle)) was created.
It let's run gradle build (with different option) while project is still Maven project.

[image]